# Text overflow elipsis

Tags: html, css, text, overflow

I am trying to add an ellipsis at the end of my text if it is too long.

The css i am currently using is:

```
style='text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;'
```

My current text should flow over a few lines, to fill the div and then have the ellipsis, however, this css is cutting the text off at the end of the first line. how do i make the ellipsis appear only when the div is filled with text?

example:

This is what i want;

```
"This is an example bit of text
that should go over multiple lines..."
```

This is what i am getting;

```
"This is an example bit of text...
```

Thanks.

Comment: It won't work without some Javascript fiddling, because the `white-space` setting you need to create an ellipsis only allows one line.

Comment: @Darryl Whalley white-space : nowrap; doesn't cut texts. you try white-space: initial;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text-overflow:ellipsis only works on a single line of text. explained [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/hub/blogs/ellipse-my-text/)..
I would recommend playing with JS.. like the article suggests. Where you can append the ellipsis, when the maximum characters allowed had been reached.

```
function shorten(text, maxLength) {
    var ret = text;
    if (ret.length > maxLength) {
        ret = ret.substr(0,maxLength-3) + "...";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: excellent, thank you for your answer